# Why am I receiving "list index out of range" in my code?

Tags: python, list, error-handling, indexing, range

I am receiving "list index out of range".  I think I'm naming one of the variables incorrectly. It might make more sense if i add the rest in then.

I am trying to print out the differences in coordinates in a list. I am certain it screws up on `str(distance_list[i])`.

Relevant code:

```
# Get the maximum distance from the user
maxDistance = float(raw_input("What is the maximum distance from the base?"))

# Set the base N,E values
#baseEasting = float(raw_input("What is the easting of the base?"))
#baseNorthing = float(raw_input("What is the northing of the base?"))
baseEasting = "346607"
baseNorthing="6274191"

#TODO: Place the values for meterological stations into the lists
stationCoords = [ [476050, 7709929],[473971,7707713],[465676,7691097] ,[515612,7702192] ,[516655,7704405],[519788,7713255],[538466,7683341] ]
numCoords = len(stationCoords)

distance_list = []
for i in range (0, numCoords):
    stationNorthing=stationCoords[i][0]
    stationEasting=stationCoords[i][1]
    distance = calculateDistance(stationNorthing, stationEasting, EASTING_BASE, NORTHING_BASE)
    if distance <= maxDistance:
# Calculate output string
        strTextOut = "Co-ordinates: " + str(distance_list[i])
        + ", at: " + str(round(distance, 0)) + " m"
        # Output the string
        print(strTextOut)
```

Hopefully that's all that is relevant. But the stationCoords already has values in it.

Comment: You are receiving "list index out of range". Fine. But at which line do you get it? The back trace is a wonderful thing. Make use of it by telling us about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`distance_list` is an empty list (because of the line `distance_list = []`), and you are attempting to read values from it with `distance_list[i]`. This is guaranteed to fail because the list is empty, so no index would be valid.

Maybe you meant to type `stationCoords[i]` instead? That makes more sense because you are attempting to print the coordinates there.

Comment: I think it worked! now the next line is saying "bad operand type for unary +: 'str'"

Comment: I'll search python again and see what the hell that means lulz

Comment: @AndrewMcVicar It means that you shouldn't have separated the line starting with `strTextOut = ` into two lines. If you do want to separate it into two lines, put \ at the end of the first.

Comment: It works now! thankyou guys. I owe you my life! I would rate but i'm not on a high enough level, but thankyou. thankyou thankyou thankyou

Comment: @AndrewMcVicar No problem. Be sure to accept the answer which solved your question by pressing the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to add a:

```
distance_list.append(distance)
```

just before your `if` statement, or similar, or just replace:

```
str(distance_list[i])
```

with

```
str(distance)
```

and get rid of `distance_list` entirely, if you don't need to access the distances later.